# Classify groups all of whose subgroups are nested

Tags: group-theory

We consider groups $G$ for which taking intersections of subgroups does not produce "new" subgroups. Let us define:

- We say that a group $G$ has the *strong nesting-subgroups property* if for any subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$, either $H \subset K$ or $K \subset H$.
- And we say $G$ has the *weak nesting-subgroups property* if for any subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $H \cap K \ne \{ e\}$ we have either $H \subset K$ or $K \subset H$.

**PROBLEM:** Classify all groups $G$ with the strong nesting-subgroups property, and classify all groups with the weak nesting-subgroups property.

If the general problem is too hard, solutions of special cases like when $G$ is finite and/or abelian etc. would also be interesting.

This was inspired by the thread [Must subgroups sharing a common element be nested in each other?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972714/)

---

**Update:** From the comments to the question it is clear that the thread found and linked by lhf covers all cases with the strong property (these groups must be abelian since for arbitrary elements $a,b\in G$ the subgroups $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ are inside each other, so $ab=ba$). *Therefore we are only interested in (partial or full) answers to the **weak** nesting-subgroups property part.*

Comment: I think that the finite groups with the strong nesting-subgroups property are exactly the cyclic groups of order power of a prime. The abelian case is treated in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203314/abelian-groups-whose-subgroup-lattice-is-chain.

Comment: As pointed out in the above comment, the strong version has already been asked and answered before, so it might be better to focus on the weak version (unfortunately, the current answer here only deals with the strong version).

Comment: Some thoughts on the weak version: I think the infinite case is intractable as it includes such things as the Tarski monster. For finite ones: The finite $p$-groups with the property are the cyclic ones and the elementary abelian ones of order $p^2$. This also immediately classifies the finite nilpotent ones as the property is inherited by subgroups. Unfortunately, such a group need not be nilpotent as $S_3$ shows, but I have a feeling that they should at least be solvable.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, my original interest was in the weak one. But regarding the strong property, is it clear from the linked thread that such a group will automatically be abelian? Just making sure the strong case is already completely covered.

Comment: Yes, the strong version implies that the group is abelian, since given any two elements, one will be in the cyclic subgroup generated by the other.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $G$ is a group havinng the weak nesting property. If $N$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ then $N$ has the weak nesting property and $G/N$ has the strong nesting property, so $G/N$ must be cyclic of prime power order.

Suppose that $G$ is a finite nonabelian simple group, let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$, and consider the (faithful) permutation representation of $G$ on the set $\Omega$ of cosets $M$ in $G$. Since Frobenius groups are not simple, there exist distinct $\alpha,\beta \in \Omega$ for which the 2-point stabilizer in this action is nontrivial. This 2-point stabilizer $G_{\alpha\beta}$  is contained in two distinct point stabilizers $G_\alpha$ and $G_\beta$ (their distinctness follows from the primitivity of the action), so $G$ does not have the weak intersection property.

So it follows by induction that a finite group with this property is solvable. We can take $N$ to be a minimal normal subgroup and then, since $N$ has the property, $N$ is either cyclic of prime order $p$ or elementary abelian of order $p^2$. Since $G/N$ is cyclic of prime power order, I expect this gives enough information to write down a completer description of all of the possible structures. But I'll leave it at that for now!

*Added later*: Verret has now shown in comments below that the only finite groups with the weak intersection property are cyclic groups of prime power order, $Z_p^2$ with $p$ prime and, for distinct primes $p,q$,  $Z_{pq}$, $Z_p \rtimes Z_q$ with nontrivial action (so $q\mid p-1$), and $Z_p^2 \rtimes Z_q$ with irreducible action (so $q \mid p+1$).

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite? Don't Tarski monsters have the weak nesting property?

Comment: Another argument for solvability is that if it were nonabelian simple then a $2$-Sylow subgroup would have order $4$ which would mean it was $A_5$ and this does not have the property.

Comment: @KeithKearnes Yes I assumed that $G$ was finite in the second and third paragraphs, but not in the first.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $A_5$ is not the only simple group with $2$-Sylow subgroup of order $4$. They are ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ with $q \equiv \pm 3 \bmod 8$. Also you need to use a big classification theorem to prove that.

Comment: Ahh, right. That was a pretty big class of groups to miss.

Comment: Starting off where Derek left off, I think one can show that the only examples with the weak property are cyclic group of prime-power order, $Z_p^2$,  $Z_p \rtimes Z_q$ and $Z_p^2 \rtimes Z_q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and, in the last case, the action of $Z_q$ on the Sylow $p$-subgroup is irreducible.

Here is a brief sketch of the proof. If $G$ is a $p$-group, then either it is elementary abelian (and we are done), or its Frattini subgroup is non-trivial. By Derek's comment, the Frattini quotient has the strong property, so must be cyclic and $G$ is also cyclic.

Comment: We may thus assume that $G$ is not a $p$-group. By Derek's argument, it is of the form $G=Z_p^a \rtimes Z_{q^b}$ with $a\in\{1,2\}$ and $b\geq 1$. Note that $G$ has a unique subgroup $M$ of order $p^aq$, and it contains every element of order $q$. In particular, $M$ intersects every Sylow $q$-subgroup non-trivially and, by the weak nesting property, $M$ must contain every Sylow $q$-subgroup and thus $b=1$. The rest is pretty obvious.

Comment: @verret Yes that looks right. I'll edit my answer.